# Horn-Schunck optical flow implementation issue

Tags: opencv, numpy, computer-vision, mathematical-optimization, opticalflow

I am trying to implement Horn-Schunck optical flow algorithm by NumPy and OpenCV
I use [Horn-Schunck method on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn%E2%80%93Schunck_method) and [original paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/papers/Optical_Flow_OPT.pdf)

But my implementation fails on following simple example

Frame1:

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

Frame2:

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 255 255   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 255 255   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

This is just small white rectangle that moves by 2 pixels on frame2
My implementation produce following flow
U part of flow (I apply np.round to every part of flow. Original values is pretty the same):

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

V part of flow:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0. -1. -0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-0. -0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-0. -1. -0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-0. -0. -0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-0. -0. -0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

It look like this flow is incorrect (Because if i move  every pixel of frame2 in direction of corresponding flow component i never get frame1)
Also my implementation fails on real images

But if i move rectangle by 1 pixel right (or left or top or down) my implementation produce:
U part of flow:

```
[[1 1 1 .....]
[1 1 1 .....]
......
[1 1 1 .....]]
```

V part of flow:

```
[[0 0 0 .....]
[0 0 0 .....]
......
[0 0 0 .....]]
```

I suppose that this flow is correct because i can reconstruct frame 1 by following procedure

```
def translateBrute(img, u, v):
    res = np.zeros_like(img)
    u = np.round(u).astype(np.int)
    v = np.round(v).astype(np.int)
    for i in xrange(img.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(img.shape[1]):
            res[i, j] = takePixel(img, i + v[i, j], j + u[i, j])
    return res
```

where takePixel is simple function that returns pixel intensity if input coordinates lays inside of image or intensity on image border otherwise

This is my implementation

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np

def takePixel(img, i, j):
    i = i if i >= 0 else 0
    j = j if j >= 0 else 0    
    i = i if i < img.shape[0] else img.shape[0] - 1
    j = j if j < img.shape[1] else img.shape[1] - 1
    return img[i, j]

#Numerical derivatives from original paper: http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/papers/Optical_Flow_OPT.pdf
def xDer(img1, img2):
    res = np.zeros_like(img1)
    for i in xrange(res.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(res.shape[1]):
            sm = 0
            sm += takePixel(img1, i,     j + 1) - takePixel(img1, i,     j)
            sm += takePixel(img1, i + 1, j + 1) - takePixel(img1, i + 1, j)
            sm += takePixel(img2, i,     j + 1) - takePixel(img2, i,     j)
            sm += takePixel(img2, i + 1, j + 1) - takePixel(img2, i + 1, j)
            sm /= 4.0
            res[i, j] = sm
    return res

def yDer(img1, img2):
    res = np.zeros_like(img1)
    for i in xrange(res.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(res.shape[1]):
            sm = 0
            sm += takePixel(img1, i + 1, j    ) - takePixel(img1, i, j    )
            sm += takePixel(img1, i + 1, j + 1) - takePixel(img1, i, j + 1)
            sm += takePixel(img2, i + 1, j    ) - takePixel(img2, i, j    )
            sm += takePixel(img2, i + 1, j + 1) - takePixel(img2, i, j + 1)
            sm /= 4.0
            res[i, j] = sm
    return res

def tDer(img, img2):
    res = np.zeros_like(img)
    for i in xrange(res.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(res.shape[1]):
            sm = 0
            for ii in xrange(i, i + 2):
                for jj in xrange(j, j + 2):
                    sm += takePixel(img2, ii, jj) - takePixel(img, ii, jj)
            sm /= 4.0
            res[i, j] = sm
    return res

averageKernel = np.array([[ 0.08333333,  0.16666667,  0.08333333],
                          [ 0.16666667,  0.        ,  0.16666667],
                          [ 0.08333333,  0.16666667,  0.08333333]], dtype=np.float32)
#average intensity around flow in point i,j. I use filter2D to improve performance. 
def average(img):
    return cv2.filter2D(img.astype(np.float32), -1, averageKernel)

def translateBrute(img, u, v):
    res = np.zeros_like(img)
    u = np.round(u).astype(np.int)
    v = np.round(v).astype(np.int)
    for i in xrange(img.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(img.shape[1]):
            res[i, j] = takePixel(img, i + v[i, j], j + u[i, j])
    return res

#Core of algorithm. Iterative scheme from wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn%E2%80%93Schunck_method#Mathematical_details
def hornShunckFlow(img1, img2, alpha):
    img1 = img1.astype(np.float32)
    img2 = img2.astype(np.float32)

    Idx = xDer(img1, img2)
    Idy = yDer(img1, img2)
    Idt = tDer(img1, img2)

    u = np.zeros_like(img1)
    v = np.zeros_like(img1)

    #100 iterations enough for small example
    for iteration in xrange(100):
        u0 = np.copy(u)
        v0 = np.copy(v)

        uAvg = average(u0)
        vAvg = average(v0)
        # '*', '+', '/' operations in numpy works component-wise
        u = uAvg - 1.0/(alpha**2 + Idx**2 + Idy**2) * Idx * (Idx * uAvg + Idy * vAvg + Idt)
        v = vAvg - 1.0/(alpha**2 + Idx**2 + Idy**2) * Idy * (Idx * uAvg + Idy * vAvg + Idt)
        if  iteration % 10 == 0:
            print 'iteration', iteration, np.linalg.norm(u - u0) + np.linalg.norm(v - v0)

    return u, v

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img1c = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
    img2c = cv2.imread(sys.argv[2])
    img1g = cv2.cvtColor(img1c, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2g = cv2.cvtColor(img2c, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    u, v = hornShunckFlow(img1g, img2g, 0.1)
    imgRes = translateBrute(img2g, u, v)
    cv2.imwrite('res.png', imgRes)
    print img1g
    print translateBrute(img2g, u, v)
```

Optimization scheme are taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn%E2%80%93Schunck_method) and numerical derivatives are taken from original paper.

Anyone have idea why my implementation produce incorrect flow?
I can provide any additional info if it necessary

PS Sorry for my poor english

UPD:
I implement Horn-Schunck cost function

```
def grad(img):
    Idx = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, np.array([
            [-1, -2, -1], 
            [ 0,  0,  0], 
            [ 1,  2,  1]], dtype=np.float32))
    Idy = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, np.array([
            [-1, 0, 1], 
            [-2, 0, 2], 
            [-1, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32))
    return Idx, Idy

def hornShunckCost(Idx, Idy, Idt, u, v, alpha):
    #return sum(sum(It**2))
    udx, udy = grad(u)
    vdx, vdy = grad(v)
    return (sum(sum((Idx*u + Idy*v + Idt)**2)) + 
            (alpha**2)*(sum(sum(udx**2)) +
                        sum(sum(udy**2)) +
                        sum(sum(vdx**2)) +
                        sum(sum(vdy**2))
                ))
```

and check value of this function inside iterations

```
if  iteration % 10 == 0:
            print 'iter', iteration, np.linalg.norm(u - u0) + np.linalg.norm(v - v0)
            print hornShunckCost(Idx, Idy, Idt, u, v, alpha)
```

If i use simple example with rectangle that has been moved by one pixel everything is ok: value of cost function decrease at every step.
But on example with rectangle that has been moved by two pixels value of cost function increase at every step. 
This behaviour of algorithm is really strange
Maybe i choose incorrect way to calculate cost function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lost a fact that classic Horn-Schunck scheme uses linearized data term (I1(x, y) - I2(x + u(x, y), y + v(x, y))). This linearization make optimization easy but disallows large displacements

To handle big displacements there are next approach [Pyramidal Horn-Schunck](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2013/20/article.pdf)